# Haskell insert an element on nth position

Tags: haskell

Hi I started to learn haskell but i can't figure out one topic.

Let's say I have a list: [1,2,3] and I'm trying to write a function to insert element on nth position. Any clues how do i do this?

Answer (score 7):

You can build an `insertAt` function like this:

```
insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt newElement 0 as = newElement:as
insertAt newElement i (a:as) = a : insertAt newElement (i - 1) as
```

One strategy for such problems is to write code for some edge cases and use recursion until an edge case is found.

The mentioned [lens](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) package simplifies handling data structures in the sense that the code may become shorter and nicer to write, but at the expense of an additional library to learn.

Both examples highlight that there are several ways to achieve a solution to your problem. I recommend having a look at the [Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) module to gain further insight into typical list operations. The [source](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#drop) for the `drop` function could be a good start for you.
Also the provided `splitAt` function could be a fitting building block for your problem.

---

As Shersh mentions correctly the above implementation of `insertAt` is somewhat flawed: It doesn't check for negative positions and in case of one given just continues recursing. This can be particularly bad in case of an infinite list.

We can easily improve the implementation by using guards:

```
insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt newElement _ [] = [newElement]
insertAt newElement i (a:as)
  | i <= 0 = newElement:a:as
  | otherwise = a : insertAt newElement (i - 1) as
```

This implementation tries to do the *right* thing by inserting the `newElement` immediately when in doubt.
It is also possible to write a version of `insertAt` that instead throws errors into our face:

```
import Data.Monoid ((<>))
import qualified Data.List as List

insertAt :: a -> Int -> [a] -> [a]
insertAt newElement i as
  | null as && i != 0 = error "Cannot insert into empty list other than position 0."
  | null as && i == 0 = [newElement]
  | i >= 0 = let (prefix, suffix) = List.splitAt i
             in prefix <> [i] <> suffix
```

This version also makes use of `List.splitAt` for brevity.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work if negative integer is passed. I think it's good technique to not fail silently at such cases but return something meaningful or forbid passing incorrect inputs.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. There is only so much won by the type system - no reason to trade the advantage of it away by writing unsafe code.

Answer (score 0):

This should work for positive and negative integers.

```
insertAt :: [a] -> a -> Int -> [a]
insertAt [] elem pos = [elem]
insertAt (x:xs) elem pos
    | pos == 0 = elem : x : xs
    | pos > 0 = x : insertAt xs elem (pos - 1) 
    | otherwise = x : insertAt xs elem ((pos) + length (x:xs) )
```

Comment: It'd have helped if the answer explained how it decided to handle negative positions. `(pos) + length (x:xs)` is the same as `length (x:xs) \`rem\` pos`, which is basically the `pos` element from the end, considering the last element at pos 1. Meaning, `insertAt [1,2] 3 -1 ==> [1,3,2]`. Also note that this answer doesn't handle positions greater than the length of the list.